# How to trace WebClient requests / response to the Application Output (Console) in MonoDevelop

Tags: c#, .net, mono, monodevelop, webclient

I'm developing a cross platform mobile app in the MonoDevelop IDE (3.0.6).
In the network layer of my app, I'm sending requests to a remote server using the `System.Net.WebClient` class.

I am able to send requests and handle the response successfully (e.g. using 
`WebClient.UploadStringAsync(..)` method and `WebClient.UploadStringCompleted` event handler), but I don't know how to see information about the requests being sent (Uri, Headers, Body, Status Code) in the Debugger's Console, this would be useful for debugging.

Does anyone know how can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WebClient class provides a bunch of properties like `Headers`, `BaseAddress`, `ResponseHeaders`and others which can help you to analyze your HTTP requests. See more [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webclient.aspx)

Since you want this info in Debugger console, use this approach. I would rather suggest use a network monitoring tool like [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2) for this.

Comment: The `UploadStringAsync` returns void, so there's no object I can use to inspect the request's Headers/etc. I'd like to see which headers were sent with the request. Do you know how can I see that?

Comment: your WebClient instance, the one which you are using to invoke UploadStringAsync should contain these properties.

Answer (score 0):

You have to manually write them to the console. You can do something like

```
Debug.WriteLine (uri.ToString ());
Debug.WriteLine (body.ToString ());
```

Etc. You just need a reference to System.Diagnostics.

Comment: Ok, The Uri and Body I already have and can write to the console as you said. But what about the Headers? See my comment in the reply above.